# Detect client disconnect when using eventsource

Tags: haskell, yesod, server-sent-events

I am trying to build a chat feature for a website in Yesod, and I want it to have a list of all the connected users that are there. I imagine the best way to do that is to add the person to the user list on a connection, and remove them when they leave. It seems that the response should block if it keeps the connection open, so I naively wrote

```
getReceiveR :: Handler ()
getReceiveR = do
  App chan <- getYesod
  req <- waiRequest
  res <- lift $ eventSourceAppChan chan req
  sendWaiResponse res
  liftIO $ putStrLn "client disconnected" <-- Note this
```

But it didn't work of course, because sendWaiResponse short circuits.

Is there any way to detect when the client disconnects?

Edit: I am using a very slighly modified version of [this tutorial](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Basic-ServerEvent-example) to test out the concept.

Comment: If you ever found a solution would you mind posting it?

Answer (score 1):

I can't really run the code to be sure, but would this work?

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource

getReceiveR :: Handler ()
getReceiveR = do
  App chan <- getYesod
  req <- waiRequest
  res <- lift $ eventSourceAppChan chan req
  register . liftIO $ putStrLn "client disconnected"
  sendWaiResponse res
```

Comment: Where is the register function from? I can't find it on google.

Comment: I guess you are referring to the one found in the resource package, but that only showed the event after I stopped the app. It might work differently in the scaffolded site, I will test that.

Comment: I know that there was a version of yesod where resources did not release until some particular time that could span several requests, but then a change was made that should cause it to release at the end of every request in newer versions of yesod.  Unfortunately I can't be any more specific than that.